# Equivalent definition of limit supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a real valued sequence $a_n$. I believe the following definition is equivalent to the usual definition of the limit supremum:

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sup\{ \omega : \omega < a_j \mbox{ for infinitely many } j\}. 
$$

Where $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} [sup_{i\ge n}a_i]$.

Proof: Let $n_k$ be a subsequence so that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k}$, and define $\beta =\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$ and $\alpha = \sup\{ \omega : \omega < a_j \mbox{ for infinitely many } j\}$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\beta \ge \alpha - \epsilon$, since by the definition of $\alpha$ there is a subsequence $a_{n_j}$ so that $a_{n_j} > \alpha - \epsilon$, and hence $\beta \ge \limsup a_{n_j} \ge \alpha - \epsilon$. Similarly $\alpha > \beta -\epsilon$, since the there are infinitly many elements of the subsequence $n_k$ so that $a_{n_k} > \beta - \epsilon$. Does this make sense? Is there a much more obvious proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, and the proof you gave seems close to optimal. We also have that
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = \inf\left\{\omega:\omega < a_j\text{ for only finitely many } j\right \}$$
which can be shown in a similar fashion. Analogous statements hold for the limit infimum.